# Is there a way to run a stored procedure at predefined intervals?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

I wanted a stored procedure to run at specified intervals everyday. Is there a way to do the same on SQL Server 2005?

I know we can create a batch file to run SP and schedule it with windows scheduled tasks but is there a way to do it from SQL Server itself?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There's a separate service called SQL Agent, which is created for this specific purpose: scheduling of tasks related to SQL Server.

This is a Windows Service that's initially disabled, so you'll have to enable that. Otherwise, it's all very straightforward: Management Studio has nice UI for managing Agent.

Answer (score 1):

You can [create jobs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186273.aspx) with sql server 2005

Answer (score 1):

Use SQL Agent to schedule jobs.

See [Creating Jobs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186273.aspx)